# Three.js: Rotate mesh onClick of another div

Tags: javascript, three.js, onclick

I have a three.js App and I am trying to change the mesh rotation inside that App by clicking on a different div, in this case "LINK". Ideally, by clicking the "LINK" div, a user would see the App content rotate to a new position. For even more control, would love to be able to set the speed of that rotation/transition.

But basically I want to change the variable below with a an onClick event:

```
 this.mesh.rotation.x = 0;
```

Just really not sure how to call that. Would love any guidance the community can offer.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r77/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dat-gui/0.5.1/dat.gui.min.js"></script>

<div class="LINK"></div>
<div class="app"></div>

<script>
class App {

    /**
     * @constructor
     */
    constructor() {

        this.width = window.innerWidth;
        this.height = window.innerHeight;


        this.DELTA_TIME = 0;
        this.LAST_TIME = Date.now();

        this.scene = new Scene(this.width, this.height);
        this.plane = new Plane();

                this.scene.add(this.plane.mesh);

        const root = document.body.querySelector('.app');
        root.appendChild(this.scene.renderer.domElement);

                this.update = this.update.bind(this)

        this.addListeners();

                requestAnimationFrame(this.update);

    }

    /**
     * @method
     * @name onResize
     * @description Triggered when window is resized
     */
    onResize() {

        this.width = window.innerWidth;
        this.height = window.innerHeight;

        this.scene.resize(this.width, this.height);

    }

    /**
     * @method
     * @name addListeners
     */
    addListeners() {

        window.addEventListener('resize', this.onResize.bind(this));

    }

    /**
     * @method
     * @name update
     * @description Triggered on every TweenMax tick
     */
    update() {

        this.DELTA_TIME = Date.now() - this.LAST_TIME;
        this.LAST_TIME = Date.now();

        this.plane.update(this.DELTA_TIME);
        this.scene.render();

                requestAnimationFrame(this.update);

    }

}

class Plane {

    /**
     * @constructor
     */
    constructor() {

        this.size = 125;
        this.segments = 125;

        this.options = new Options();
        this.options.initGUI();

        this.uniforms = {
            u_amplitude: { value: this.options.amplitude },
            u_frequency: { value: this.options.frequency },
            u_time: { value: 0.0 }
        }

        this.geometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(this.size, this.size, this.segments, this.segments);
        this.material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
            uniforms: this.uniforms,
            vertexShader: document.getElementById('planeVS').innerHTML,
            fragmentShader: document.getElementById('planeFS').innerHTML,
            side: THREE.DoubleSide,
                        wireframe: true
        });

        this.mesh = new THREE.Mesh(this.geometry, this.material);
        this.mesh.rotation.x = 0;

    }

    /**
     * @method
     * @name update
     * @description Triggered on every TweenMax tick
     * @param {number} dt - DELTA_TIME
     */
    update(dt) {

        this.uniforms.u_amplitude.value = this.options.amplitude;
        this.uniforms.u_frequency.value = this.options.frequency;
        this.uniforms.u_time.value += dt / 1250;

    }

}

class Scene extends THREE.Scene {

    /**
     * @constructor
     */
    constructor(width, height) {

                super();

        this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true, alpha: true });
        this.renderer.setSize(width, height);


        this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(50, width / height, 1, 2000);
        this.camera.position.z =170;



    }

    /**
     * @method
     * @name render
     * @description Renders/Draw the scene
     */
    render() {

        this.renderer.autoClearColor = true;
        this.renderer.render(this, this.camera);
        this.renderer.setClearColor(0x000000, 0);


    }

    /**
     * @method
     * @name resize
     * @description Resize the scene according to screen size
     * @param {number} newWidth
     * @param {number} newHeight
     */
    resize(newWidth, newHeight) {

        this.camera.aspect = newWidth / newHeight;
        this.camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

        this.renderer.setSize(newWidth, newHeight);

    }

}

class Options {

    /**
     * @constructor
     */
    constructor() {

        this.amplitude = 10.0;
        this.frequency = 0.08;

        this.gui = new dat.GUI();

    }

    /**
     * @method
     * @name initGUI
   * @description Initialize the dat-gui
     */
    initGUI() {



    }

}



new App();
</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? I don't see any event listener for the `LINK` `<div>`...

Comment: @TheJim01I just really do not have a grasp on where to begin - including what to include in the EventListener request beyond listening for the LINK click. Novice here.

Comment: Unless someone is feeling especially generous, I don't think you'll get the nudge you're looking for here. Stack Overflow concentrates on answerable questions, not providing tutorials and instruction. You can try the [three.js forum](https://discourse.threejs.org/), but you'll likely get a similar response. I suggest you do some research on JavaScript events (how they work, how to use them), and manipulating objects in three.js scenes. Then try to implement what you want, and update your question when you get stuck or encounter errors.